# What determines what base the right side of this base coversion will be?

Tags: exponentiation, number-systems, decimal-expansion

Referring to [this example of positional notation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Exponentiation):

> [image]

There are several examples

$$465\;\;\text{(base 10)} = 465\;\;\text{(base 10)}$$

But then

$$465\;\;\text{(base 7)} = 243\;\;\text{(base 10)}$$

Why is the right hand side considered as base $10$?  Wouldn't it be a base $7$ after the conversion using positional notation?  Is the result always base $10$?

And Why doesn't the base-16 example result in a base 10 number

[image]

Comment: "465base7 = 243base10" means "the number represented by 465 in base 7 is the same number that the one represented by 243 in base 10"

Comment: @Tryss I noticed someone added the tag decimal expansion, is that the proper term for this procedure of converting as in the examples?

Answer (score 1):

What determines it is the author's choice, nothing more. I can convert from base $285$ to base $57$ if I want, for example
$$3\;\;\text{(base 285)}=3\;\;\text{(base 57)}$$
It's just that in current society, we think of numbers "by default" in base $10$, so writing something in base $10$ feels like the standard thing to convert to. There's nothing mathematically special about it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help you better understand the specific example you bring up:
$$
(465)_\color{red}{7}=4(\color{red}{7^2})+6(\color{red}{7})+5=(243)_{\color{blue}{10}}=2(\color{blue}{10^2})+4(\color{blue}{10})+3.
$$
Does it make sense now? Converting something from base-$16$ to base-$10$ is not an issue--simply do as above; however, converting a base-$10$ number (or a lower number base) to base-$16$ is *slightly* problematic only in the sense that you have to actually *invent* or *come up with* the symbols that you will use for bases $10,11,\ldots,15$.

Comment: I don't know, I just don't get why the subscript on 243 is automatically a 10 what is it about the calculation that determines this?  Something about the numbers used in the calculation?

Comment: @erotavlas It is not *automatically* a $10$--it's simply a base-conversion example. You can also convert $(465)_7$ to base-$3$ if you prefer:
$$
(465)_7 = (10000)_3.
$$

Comment: Your equation above always yields a result in base 10.  Why?  How did you know the result 243 is base 10 using that particular calculation?

Comment: @erotavlas What do you mean my equation (what equation?) always yields a result in base 10? I knew $(465)_7$ was $243$ in base 10 because I **expanded** it. That's what you need to do to see how it all works. It's the same as for how I converted $(465)_7$ into base 3.

Comment: I mean the calculation in your answer.  You say you expanded it (I assume 465), according to the general equation that is written in the article on Positional Notation from Wikipedia.  Does the conversion to base 3 follow the same equation?

Comment: @erotavlas You can actually check for yourself: $(10000)_3=1(3^5)=(?)_{10}$

Comment: Ok, from what I understand so far, the above expansion is a decimal expansion.  Using it you can convert any number of any base into a number in base 10.  From there you can convert from the base 10 representation back to any other base. Is that right?

Comment: @erotavlas That is correct. Make sense now?